# ToTitleCase() method is not working with Special Characters

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, case-conversion

I have a string that needs to be converted such that it converts first character to Upper case. with ToTitleCase method it works fine except for the case when there is a special characters.

Below is the code and expected result

```
String textToConvert= "TEST^S CHECK"
TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;
       return myTI.ToTitleCase(textToConvert.ToLower())
```

Expected result: Test^s Check
But the result is coming out as Test^S Check with "S" converted to capital after special character ^

Is there anyway to change th conversion to expected result

Comment: Not with `ToTitleCase`, though they do reserve the rights to make the function slower in the future ;) - for this, now, you'll have to roll your own (which should not be hard to do).

Comment: What would you expect this string to become? `"TEST.S CHECK"`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: It should be Test.s Check

Comment: Symbol `^` is called "Circumflex accent"and in Unicode is declared as "modifier symbol". In C# there is a [small static function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/textinfo.cs,b51cc381eb6a95dc) that determines if character is word delimiter, and modifier symbols are word delimiters. This means that the following character S is a separate word as far as .NET is concerned.

Comment: Just be aware that ToTitleCase is actually working just fine, it's just that what you want is not what it supports. In other words, this handling is not a bug, it's supposed to be like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToTitleCase` is a handy method, but if you need more fine grained control, Regex might be the better option:

```
string titleCase = Regex.Replace(textToConvert.ToLower(), @"^[a-z]|(?<= )[a-z]",
    match => match.Value.ToUpper());
```

`^[a-z]|(?<=\s)[a-z]` will match a letter at the start of the string, and letters preceded by whitespace (space, tab or newline).

Comment: I suggest at least `?<=\s` - preceded by *white*space (i.e., space, tab, nonbreaking space etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `ToTitleCase` turn 1st letter of *each word* to upper case while all the other to lower case.
*Word* in terms of .Net is a *consequent letters*, and, alas, `^` is not a letter, that's why `TEST^S` consists of `2` words.

We can redefine word as

- word *must* start from letter
- word *can* contain letters, apostrophes `'`, circumflexes `^`, and full stops `.`

In this case we can use *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ... 

  string source = "TEST^S CHECK по-русски (in RUSSIAN) it's a check! a.b.c.d";

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\p{L}[\p{L}\^'\.]*",
    match => match.Value.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + match.Value.Substring(1).ToLower());

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  Test^s Check По-Русски (In Russian) It's A Check! A.b.c.d
```